# Why doesn't UIImagePickerController delegate to my Object class?

Tags: ios, swift, uiimagepickercontroller

```
class CameraPicker: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
weak var viewController:MyProfileVC!

 func launchCamera() {
        if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera) {
            let imagePicker:UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
            imagePicker.delegate = self
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.camera
            imagePicker.cameraDevice = UIImagePickerControllerCameraDevice.front
            imagePicker.cameraCaptureMode = .photo
            imagePicker.allowsEditing = false

            self.viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } }
}
func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) { 
        print("didFinishPickingMedia")
}
```

This is my object class function, but 'didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo' function doesn't get called after taking the picture. Also, the viewcontroller which is presenting the imagepicker is a different Swift file

Comment: are you trying this on simulator or phone?, it won't work on simulator, as simulator doesn't have camera

Comment: I'm trying this on my phone

Comment: @Dee Have you add `NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription` in info.plist?

Comment: Yes I have Nirav D, thanks for reminding me. I have resolved the issue now, so thank you for your help and I apologise for the late response.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and I've found a solution, so I'm posting my version (I'm taking a picture from the photo library but it's the same :) ).

I had a memory management issue. 
I've created an IBAction function where I instantiated my camera handler class (with the delegate inside...). At the end of the function the variable goes out of scope and it's deallocated. To solve the issue I've made it as instance variable.

That's my code for the VC with my UiButton:

```
class STECreateUserVC: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var imgAvatar: UIImageView!
    let cameraHandler = STECameraHandler()

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        cameraHandler.importPictureIn(self) { [weak self] (image) in
            self?.imgAvatar.image = image
        }
    }
}
```

...and that's my handler:

```
class STECameraHandler: NSObject {

    let imagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    var completitionClosure: ((UIImage) -> Void)?

    func importPictureIn(_ viewController: UIViewController, completitionHandler:((UIImage) -> Void)?) {
        completitionClosure = completitionHandler
        imagePickerController.delegate = self
        imagePickerController.allowsEditing = true
        imagePickerController.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePickerController.mediaTypes = UIImagePickerController.availableMediaTypes(for: .photoLibrary)!
        viewController.present(imagePickerController, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

extension STECameraHandler: UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : Any]) {
        if let completitionClosure = completitionClosure, let image = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage] as? UIImage {
            completitionClosure(image)
        }
        imagePickerController.dismiss(animated: true)
    }
}
```

I've used a closure in order to have a cleaner code.

Answer (score -1):

This:

```
self.viewController.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

should be:

```
self.present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The class has no viewcontroller. I created the class to handle all the UIImagePicker functions so I created a weak reference to the viewcontroller that uses the class which is how I am managing to present the imagePicker

Comment: How did you pass reference of your actual view controller to `weak var viewController:MyProfileVC!`?

Comment: Sorry for late response. in the initializer method for CameraPicker, I added an argument for the sender to reference itself into the weak variable

Comment: Yes I have resolved the issue, thank you very much Mr.Bista for following up on my issue. I appreciate it :)

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem... how did you solve it? Can you please post your code? Thank you! :)

Comment: I am deeply sorry DungeonDev, this was so long ago and the code is much different now. If you have an issue please post your detailed question and send me the link and I will do my best to help you solve your problem.